# no closing "X" with inline content

Tags: magnific-popup

I'm using magnificPopup twice on the page: www.thisismaceo.com/test.php

first button (VIDEO, at bottom) opens the lightbox popup and has a close "x"
second button (AUDIO) opens the lightbox popup but has no close "x".

I tried so many options, including

```
inline: {
  markup: '<div class="soundcloud-popup">'+
  '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
  '<div class="mfp-content"></div>'+
  '</div>'
}
```

to no avail.

any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look closer :)

[image]

```
#soundcloudplayer {
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, same thing happened to me.